# Javascript use decorator to change static class field value?

Tags: javascript, decorator

Is it possible for a JS field decorator to change its value?

A simplified use case would be something like this:

```
const addItem = (newValue) => {
  return function (target) {
    target.value.push(newValue);
  };
};

class Test {
  @addItem(4)
  static values = [1,2,3];
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test.constructor.values) // [1,2,3,4]
```

Using the following experimental decorators:

```
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators',
  {
    version: '2018-09',
    decoratorsBeforeExport: true,
  },
```

End goal is to make a decorator to inject tailwind style sheets into a `lit` elements `static styles`. Currently using a mixin for this but just doing this for fun and to learn whats possible with decorators.

### Update to Barmars comments

When trying to return a value from the inner function, I end up getting an error:

```
export const addItem = (value) => {
  return function (target) {
    return [value];
  };
};

Uncaught TypeError: An element descriptor's .kind property must be either "method" or "field", but a decorator created an element descriptor with .kind "undefined"
```

Looking at the documentation, the variables getting passed to each of these functions doesn't seem to match either.

```
function logged(value, { kind, name }) {
  if (kind === "field") {
    return function (initialValue) {
      console.log(`initializing ${name} with value ${initialValue}`);
      return initialValue;
    };
  }
}
```

When running that example, the 2nd parameter to logged() is undefined. "initialValue" also is an object, not the value:

```
Object { kind: "field", key: "styles", placement: "own", descriptor: {…}, initializer: value(), … }
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to work. The [decorator proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators) says: **a decorator can replace a method with another method, a field with another field, a class with another class, and so on**

Comment: See the description of decorators for class fields here: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#class-fields

Comment: Updated my question with more details. Doesn't seem like the decorator syntax I'm seeing matches with that proposal. All the arguments to the functions are different. Guessing thats for a much newer version of the proposal than 2018. Unfortunately, Lit.js only supports the 2018 proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nicolo Ribaudo was able to help me over on Babel's discussions. The correct way to do this is to use the initializer function:

```
const addItem = (newValue) => {
  return function (target) {
    const { initializer } = target;
    target.initializer = function () {
      return [
        ...initializer.call(this),
        newValue,
      ];
    };
  };
};

class Test {
  @addItem(4)
  static values = [1,2,3];
}

const test = new Test();
console.log(test.constructor.values) // [1,2,3,4]
```